# Understanding exactly what the pretrained model does on the Tensorflow object detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to understand what I need from any pre-trained model used in the API regardless of any additional code found on the Tensorflow object detection API. 
For example: `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17`, depending on what I have understood: it is a model that is already trained to detect objects (there is a classification to know the category of the object + Regression to bound the objects with rectangles and those rectangles are actually the x,y,w,h coordinates on the object).

How do we benefit from the regression output of that model (x,y,w,h coordinates) to use them in another model?

Let's assume we want to print out just the coordinates x,y,w,h of a detected object on an image without any need of the code of Tensorflow object detection API, how can we do that?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to print the bounding box coordinates of a detected object without using the object detection API? Also what do you mean by "how do you benefit from the output of the regression model" ? Are you looking for applications of the object detection API?

Comment: @VishnuDasu  "you want to print the bounding box coordinates of a detected object without using the object detection API?" yeah I just want to see one x one y one h one w of one sole rectangle of one object, I have tried this: output_dict['detection_boxes'] on the object detection api, it has outputed many many coordinates which is not what I look for. My question is: how can I just use this previous pre-trained model on an image to just output x,y,w,h without any need to bound a rectangle and without any need of the object detection API?
Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: ""how do you benefit from the output of the regression model" ? Are you looking for applications of the object detection API? " I have already specified the application which is robotic grasping, basically what I'd like to know besides printing the x,y,w,h coordinates is how i will send them to my robot, one possible option is to use ROS which I am a bit familiar with. At the moment I carry about printing the x,y,h,w coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you can use the pretrained model provided in tensorflow object detection model zoo without installing object detection api. The alternative solution is to use opencv.

Opencv has provided both c++ and python api to call `.pb` models generated by tensorflow. [Here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API) is a nice tutorial.